# Running LXD containers on centos?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, lxc

I've just discovered LXD and this technology sounds amazing. The power of virtual machines with the cost of normal linux processes! However, I'm not able to find any information on how to run LXD on centos.

It looks like LXD started as a project in 2014, so it has existed for several years now. How come I can't do "yum install lxd" on centos?

Am I over-estimating the usefulness of LXD?

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue on the Lxd Github page (https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2984) about this.  Basically it will work on Fedora but it takes more work to get it to work on Centos.  Centos is missing several of the required go dependencies.

You will need to add a Fedora repo (https://github.com/ganto) before `yum install` works.